# How do Git's @{upstream} and @{push} differ?

Tags: git, git-config, git-rev-parse

What's the difference between a Git branch's `@{upstream}` and the newer `@{push}`?

As I understand it `@{upstream}` is the branch's upstream tracking ref, and `@{push}` is the ref a `push` will push to. To my intuition those are the same thing. Checking several handy branches `git rev-parse @{upstream}` is the same as `git rev-parse @{push}`, and (I thought possibly one would not resolve in the same way) `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{upstream}` is the same as `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{push}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@{upstream}` and  `@{push}` indeed point to the same thing... *when they do*.

Jokes aside, I mean this is only coincidentally true, it's a consequence of two config entries pointing to the same remote, but they could be different.

There's an excellent example on [this page](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Specifically, this part :

> The suffix `@{push}` reports the branch "where we would push to" if git push were run while branchname was checked out (or the current `HEAD` if no branchname is specified). Since our push destination is in a remote repository, of course, we report the local tracking branch that corresponds to that branch (i.e., something in `refs/remotes/`).

```
$ git config push.default current
$ git config remote.pushdefault myfork
$ git switch -c mybranch origin/master

$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}
refs/remotes/origin/master

$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{push}
refs/remotes/myfork/mybranch
```

> Note in the example that we set up a triangular workflow, where we pull from one location and push to another. In a non-triangular workflow, `@{push}` is the same as `@{upstream}`, and there is no need for it.

Comment: Makes sense. Hadn't seen that doc before, assumed something like it existed but the terms are search engine friendly! Cross-referencing that with the git-pull docs, is it fair to think of `@{upstream}` as `@{pull-also-default-fetch-also-default-push}`?

Comment: * are _not_ search engine friendly

Comment: Yes (if I understand your comment correctly), by default these point to the same branch, and also usually, they're named the same. But beware of assumptions :-)

Comment: See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a13943ef4e671235cacef7d1612c8765d1312a9